# how to pass text, button and icon to v-radio elements

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

```
<VRadioGroup :multiple="multiple" v-model="radioGroup">
      <VRadio
        v-for="(item, index) in options"
        :key="index"
        :label="item.text"
        :value="item.value"
      >
       </VRadio>
    </VRadioGroup>
```

I got something like this.

**Question 1)** I want user to be able to select all of them or as many as he wants. Looks like :multiple="true" or multiple doesn't work. I can only select one. I should also be able to unselect any of them.

**Question 2)** beside each `v-radio`, I want to have its name, button and icon. I tried the following thing(All I could find was `v-radio has a label slot.` I tried this:

```
<template slot="label" slot-scope="data">
          {{ data.item.text }}
          <VBtn @click="removeRadioButton(item.value)" ripple
            ><BaseIcon name="minus-circle" />&nbsp;</VBtn
          >
        </template>
```

I put this between `VRadio tags`. Looks like each of them has a button and icon, but it gives me error. (item of undefined). seems like data in `slot-scope is undefined.`

Comment: Do you have to use radio inputs ? because i couldn't find any way to do that with `vuetify` but its is possible with `v-checkbox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer 1:
It is simple. You can change the type radioGroup to an array.
It will work.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid px-0>
      {{radioGroup}}
      <v-radio-group 
         v-model="radioGroup"
         multiple=true>
        <v-radio
          v-for="n in 3"
          :key="n"
          :label="`Radio ${n}`"
          :value="n"
        ></v-radio>
      </v-radio-group>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      radioGroup: []
    }
  },
})
```

Note: But For multiple selections, you shouldn't use radio buttons. Go for Checkbox.

Answer 2:

Issue In your code: You're looping on the radio button.

If you want some different text on before all radio buttons then you need to loop on a div which will contain the text and icons.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid px-0>
      {{radioGroup}}

      <v-radio-group 
         v-model="radioGroup"
         multiple="true">
        <div 
          v-for="n in 3"
          :key="n"
         >
          <span class="d-inline">
            {{n}}  
          </span>
          <v-radio
           class="d-inline"
          :label="`Radio ${n}`"
          :value="n"
        ></v-radio>
          <span>
            icon here
          </span>
        </div>

      </v-radio-group>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But checkbox doesn't have checkbox group thing. So I had to do it myself. Why not radio button group?

Comment: 1) it works what you suggested, but i can't uncheck them after i check them.

Comment: @NikaKurashvili  Radio buttons are used to choose only one of a predefined set of mutually exclusive options. In case you want to select multiple options then you definitely need checkboxes.

Comment: And you can loop over the v-checkbox . here's a quick example . https://codepen.io/harshittpandey/pen/GVBBME?editors=1010